# Meaning of __init function qualifier in linux kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel

What is the meaning of a `__init` qualifier to a function in this context:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/thermal/of-thermal.c?v=3.16#L746

How does that function get executed?

Comment: Yeas, it's duplicate. `__init` means that function will be removed from RAM once initialization stage is done. Just to save some memory.

Comment: And is there anything that can be done to ensure it executes?  I don't understand how this gets called.  Sorry I know out of scope of original question.

Comment: Sure. Just looking to how this function used further can tell you if it will be executed (well, if you are experienced enough). Also you can just put some `printk` trace to the beginning of that function and see if it appears in kernel log (`dmesg`).

Comment: Look at [thermal_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/thermal/thermal_core.c?v=3.16#L1819) function (line 1819). It's being called from there. Now see [where thermal_init() is called](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.16;i=thermal_init) and try to figure out if it's gonna be executed on your platform or not.